Script not running on sudo cronjob
I have a script I'm trying to run on restart.  This is in Ubuntu 24.04 (VM in Proxmox).  I can manually execute the script without any issue.
I have set it up via sudo crontab -e with this basic command:
@reboot <username> /home/<insert rest of the path here>/start-server.sh

However, it doesn't seem to run on restart.  I've tried executing a restart command in terminal and also just shutting down and restarting the VM.  No difference.  I've tried it with and without the specified user.
When I run it in the terminal though, it starts immediately.  I'm a bit stumped as to what would cause this.  Anything obvious I'm missing?
The cron.service shows it's trying to run the script.

crontab has very limited set of folders in its PATH variable. Make sure the commands in your start-server.sh script also include full path of all the commands and files. You may want to at a some sleep time so that the VM fully starts and network etc. are connected before the command is executed. Try @reboot sleep 300 && /home/<your_username>/start-server.sh. If you need more help, copy and paste the content of your script in the above question.

... and it might be helpful to change your command to something like @reboot /home/username/start-server.sh > /home/username/start-server.log 2>&1 to capture diagnostic output
